# Regex in Java: Capture last {n} words

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am trying to do regex in java, I need to capture the last {n} words. (There may be a variable num of whitespaces between words). Requirement is it has to be done in regex. 
So e.g. in

```
The man  is very   tall.
```

For n = 2, I need to capture

```
very   tall.
```

So I tried

```
(\S*\s*){2}$
```

But this does not match in java because the initial words have to be consumed first. So I tried

```
^(.*)(\S*\s*){2}$
```

But .* consumes everything, and the last 2 words are ignored. 
I have also tried

```
^\S?\s?(\S*\s*){2}$
```

Anyone know a way around this please?

Comment: Please share your code, it is difficult to understand what you are up to from the examples. I think you need `var rx = "(?s)^(.*?)(\\S+\\s*){2}$"` if you are using `String#matches`.

Comment: Please post full relevant code.

Comment: Please give some feedback to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You had almost got it in your first attempt.

Just change `+` to `*`.

The plus sign means at least one character, because there wasn't any space the match had failed.

On the other hand the asterisk means from zero to more, so it will work.

Look it live here: [`(?:\S*\s*){2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/zG7kL9/2)

Using `replaceAll` method, you could try this regex: [`((?:\\S*\\s*){2}$)|.`](http://ideone.com/xaWM8V)

Comment: Ah good catch, but it still does not match...it needs the initial characters to be specified/consumed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, can you show the correct output?

Comment: See above, I need to capture 'very      tall'. With all the spaces in between (which this editor is not allowing)

Comment: @user2689782. For me, it is working.. have you openned the link I had posted?

Comment: It works for me in the regex testers, just not in java. The link you posted gives an illegal state exception in java. Basically, I need a way to capture the earlier characters lazily.

Comment: @user2689782: Are you using `String#matches()`? Use `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: @user2689782. I did [this snippet](http://ideone.com/xaWM8V) .. but, It certainly could be better. Some `java` coder could help better with this.

Comment: I am using Matcher.groups()

Answer (score 1):

[Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/jX6lE1/1) contains - as you already mention - a greedy subpattern that eats up the whole string and sine `(\S*\s*){2}` can match an empty string, it matches an empty location at the end of the input string.

Lazy dot matching (changing `.*` to `.*?`) [won't do the whole job](http://%5E(.*?)(%5CS*%5Cs*)%7B2%7D$) since the capturing group is quantified, and the `Matcher.group(1)` will be set to the last captured non-whitespaces with optional whitespaces. *You need to set the capturing group around the quantified group.*

Since you most likely are using `Matcher#matches`, you can use

```
String str = "The man  is very   tall.";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(.*?)((?:\\S*\\s*){2})"); // no need for `^`/`$` with matches()
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches()) {                  // Group 2 contains the last 2 "words"
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // => very   tall.
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OSkUJ4)

Comment: Please check my answer, and let me know if there is anything unclear.